# Simple SQL update statement from select with undesired results

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Below is the statement

```
UPDATE
  [dbName].[dbo].[tableName]
SET
  [tableName].[columnName] = NULL
SELECT
  [tableName]
FROM [dbName].[dbo].[tableName]
WHERE
  [columnName] like 'match%'
```

I thought that the only values in columnName beginning with 'match' would be replaced with 'NULL' however, to my surprise all values in columnName were replaced.

Would appreciate some explanation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running two different SQL statements because you have the syntax wrong:

```
UPDATE
  [dbName].[dbo].[tableName]
SET
  [tableName].[columnName] = NULL
```

...and...

```
SELECT
  [tableName]
FROM [dbName].[dbo].[tableName]
WHERE
  [columnName] like 'match%'
```

The first `UPDATE` sets all rows in the table to NULL. The second `SELECT` then returns all rows where `[columnName] like 'match%'` (of which there will be none as you've just set them all to NULL).

You want

```
UPDATE
      [dbName].[dbo].[tableName]
SET
      [tableName].[columnName] = NULL
WHERE
      [columnName] like 'match%'
```

The syntax with a `FROM` clause (but no `SELECT`) would be:

```
UPDATE
      [dbName].[dbo].[tableName]
SET
      [tableName].[columnName] = NULL
FROM 
      [dbName].[dbo].[tableName]
WHERE
      [columnName] like 'match%'
```

...which then allows you to use `JOIN`s etc.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to perform an update through a select. 
May I ask how would I accomplish that using the same example?

Comment: Hi @Rob I've updated the answer with the syntax you are looking for. You can't use a `SELECT` but you can use `FROM`.